# ESD Protection diode polarity

Tags: diodes, datasheet, pcb-assembly, polarity

I'm using the following ESD protection diode:

[image]

On the datasheet it says:

> MOUNTING POSITION: Any

**Does it mean I can assemble it at any polarity?**
(switch cathode and anode connections)

Comment: That datasheet quote sounds like a challenge to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Bidirectional ESD/TVS are agnostic to mounting position because either way presents exactly the same electrical characteristics - both terminals are ANODES

Comment: Just to add, not all bidirectional ESD/TVS diodes are symmetrical, so sometimes the mounting position can be important

Comment: @BeB00 but can I assume the the phrase "MOUNTING POSITION: Any" on the datasheet means that the diode **is** symmetrical?

Comment: It is not just one diode, as you can see in the scematic you posted. Just trace the path though that device from left to right and then the other way around - do you see any difference? No, I don't think so. As long as both diodes have the same characteristic, and they will, the DEVICE is symmetrical.

Comment: @AmirGonnen, you don't have to assume anything. You can see that the equivalent circuit diagram posted in your question is clearly symmetrical.

Comment: I mean really the best thing to do is just look at the datasheet. If that comment on the schematic weren't there, I wouldn't rely on the schematic symbol accurately showing the symmetry of the diodes